Gunicorn with Flask to produce Kafka message takes 20% cpu for one request
I'm building a testing tool to produce Kafka message using confluent-kafka library. I'm wrapping the producer with Flask to get value and key for each produce message from post body, so that from any rest client load testing tool we can push concurrent messages to performance test.
I'm using the flask app with gunicorn. But with single request to the app, the cpu% is at 20% for 4 core processor.
I don't have code with me. Any idea why it could be?
